# Functions inside iframe execute before js libraries are loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe that contains the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_container"></div>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'some_url',
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      console.log(data.html); // <div><link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css' rel='stylesheet'><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js'></script><script>  $('.input-select2').select2();</script><select class='input-select2'></select></div>
      $('#my_container').html(data.html);
    },
  });
</script>
```

As you see the script inside the iframe pulls a string of HTML/js from an external resource and appends it to `#my_container`. The pulled HTML/js is:

```
<div>
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    $('.input-select2').select2();
  </script>
  <select class='input-select2'></select>
</div>
```

But when the appended scripts run, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

So apparently the `select2` function is executed before the library is loaded. If I move the `select2.min.js` library one level up to the `jquery.min.js` library everything works just fine. Or if I wrap my `select2` function in `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 20);` it also works.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, it seems that your jquery snippet is executed before select2 was loaded.

Maybe can you dynamically load the select2 lib with an ajax call, to ensure the library loading.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js",
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(){
    $('.input-select2').select2();
  }
});
```

As you say, you can also wrap your select2 initialization in a setTimeout() function. It's an unelegant known solution but it works.

See this post: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: Thanks @roundge but it seems like loading the library with ajax isn't really a solution but rather a hack to circumvent it.